# Guy is on voyage to Mars. He thinks his wife is with him but she's a hypnotic suggestion

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

There's no room for a second person, so he's been hypnotized to believe that she's there.

Fuzzy on the details.  Story's probably from 1950s.

**What is the name of this story?**

Answer (score 5):

Theodore Sturgeon's story [“Who?”](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45836) (March 1955 Galaxy; vt “Bulkhead” in *A Way Home*, coll 1955) is about the deliberate splitting of an astronaut's personality to save him from insanity during a long space flight alone.  However, I believe the other personality was a rival astronaut and not his wife, so this may not be the correct id.

Summary from **Jennre Blog** [HERE](http://jennre.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/bulkhead-theodore-sturgeon-1955/)

> “Bulkhead,” Theodore Sturgeon, 1955 – A cadet and captain-in-training
> endures an extended “test run” simulation in a facsimile of a typical
> ship.  He’s been told that if he presses a button, he can communicate
> with another cadet, but he resists the temptation to need human
> contact due to pride.  When he finally presses the button, he finds
> that a young boy (Skampi) has been sealed inside the bulkhead.  Skampi
> is miserably lonely, crying, and the cadet is disgusted.  Worse, an
> irrational fury seizes him when the boy asks to learn more about
> piloting.  He assumes that the boy is the real candidate and that his
> role is to train him.  He assembles a diamond-tipped drill to get
> through the bulkhead and to the boy, with the intent of murdering him.
> Slowly, he regains control of his emotions, feels pity for the boy, so
> pathetic, trapped.  He resolves to teach the boy, despite his
> reservations.
>
> When the run is complete, months (?) later, the psychodynamics (PD)
> men explain that the bulkhead was empty.  They reveal that every cadet
> has his childhood memories suppressed through hypnosis.  The boy in
> the bulkhead was a version of himself in his youth–weak, pathetic,
> bullied–with whom he needed to empathize, to prevent childish behavior
> and unresolved issues from childhood from appearing under the stress
> and isolation of space travel.  While the cadet seems to accept this
> explanation, he also earnestly asks after the situation of the boy.
> He’d like to be reassigned with the boy on his next mission, he
> explains. It’s implied that PD has intentionally made him into a
> schitzophrenic in order to better suit him for space travel.  In the
> closing lines, he takes his inner child out for ice cream.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not the answer because it doesn't match 100%, but in Philip Dick's short story ["I Hope I Shall Arrive Soon"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Hope_I_Shall_Arrive_Soon) (alternative title: Frozen Journey), a man wakes up en route to a colony world due to a glitch in his cryosleep chamber. He is awake but cannot move or do anything except thinking, and since the trip will take years, the ship's AI decides to make its passenger sleep while replaying his memories back to him in order to stop him from going mad. The man's wife plays a big part in those memories.

(Of course, this being a Phil Dick story, things quickly turn weird).

Comment: I was thinking about the same story... It was traslated to Spanish as "Suspensión Deficiente", published in "El Péndulo Magazine", issue 10 from Second Era.

Comment: @JuanZe "El Péndulo"! Genial revista. Tengo sólo un par de números, lamentablemente :)

Comment: I knew it with the title "Frozen Journey" instead of "I hope I shall arrive soon"

Comment: @JuanZe Thanks, I've added the alternative title in my answer. I only knew the title listed in [The Collected Stories of Philip K. Dick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Collected_Stories_of_Philip_K._Dick). Usually -- but not always -- they list each story with the preferred title by PKD, before it got changed by the editor.

Comment: @AndresF.: The [internet science fiction data base](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58203) is a useful resource.

Comment: @user14111 Thanks! That's indeed very useful. [This is the one I own](http://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/b/bb/WCNRMMBRTF1991.jpg). I love SF book covers.

Comment: You're welcome, but I botched the name of the site: the "SF" does not stand for "**science** fiction", it's the Internet Speculative Fiction Database. Oops.